# query the number of intersected segments in a rage

Tags: algorithm

I have a large dataset of segments `(ai, bi)`, where `ai < bi`, and many queries. Each query asks for the number of intersected segments with the given range `(b, e)`. The number of queries can be very large. A naive algorithm is to search for all intersected segments per query which takes O(N) time apparently. Is there a faster way to do this? I can imagine soring the segments dataset in ascending order of `ai` may help but I don't know what to do with the other direction.

```
segments: [1, 3], [2, 6], [4, 7], [7, 8] 
query 1: [2, 5] => output [1, 3] [2, 6], [4, 7]
...
```

Comment: Different a little bit, but related. You may find some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60643340/good-algorithm-for-a-query-related-problem/60656577#60656577

Answer (score 2):

Make list `B` of sorted start points, as you wrote.

Make list `P` of structures containing all points - both starting and ending points together with field `SE = +1/-1` for start and end correspondingly. Sort it by point coordinate.

Make `Active = 0`. Walk through `P`, adding `SE` to `Counter` and making new list `A` containing point position and `Active` count.

For every query start search (with binary search) lower position in `A`, get `Active` - number of opened segments at this moment.

Then search indexes in `B` corresponding to query start and query end, get index difference - number of segments starting inside query interval.

Sum of these values is needed `number of intersected segments` (you don't need segments themselves according to the problem statement)

Time per query is `O(log(N))`

```
[1, 3], [2, 6], [4, 7], [7, 8]                       initial list
[1, 2, 4, 7]                                         list B
(1,1),(2,1),(3,-1),(4,1),(6,-1),(7,-1),(7,1),(8,-1)  list P
(1,1),(2,2),(3,1), (4,2),(6,1), (7,0), (7,1),(8,0)   list A 
        ^
q start 2 gives active = 2 (two active intervals)

searching 2 in B gives index 1, searching 5 gives index 2, 
difference is 1  
result = 2 + 1 = 3
```

Comment: I don't understand the lookup in your example. (especially where do you search 5, and why it resolves 3).
On the side, I think you miss the self closing intervals ? 
e.g [1, 3], [2, 6], [3,3.1],[3.1,3.2]... [4,7] for query [2,5] would count the diff of active suff but since inbetween we have invariant 0, we are missing the [3.x, 3.x+eps]

Comment: @grodzi  Corrected off-by-1 error, added some explanations. We won't loose  `[3.x, 3.x+eps]` intervals because they start between query points and will be counted in the second part.